# How do I delete file windows with ruby

Tags: ruby

```
files = Dir.new("F:/data/").entries.grep(/.*_communities_.*.dat/) || []
fp = File.new(f, "r")
fp.close
File.delete(f)
```

doesn't work 
and i also try `DEL #{file}`
or
`system("DEL #{file}")`
 It don't work too

Comment: Where are you setting variable f?

Answer (score 2):

```
Dir.entries("F:/data").grep(/.+_communities_.+.dat/).each do |file|
  File.delete("F:/data/" + file)
end
```

This is what you want to do? I don't understand well your question.